# How to enable live reload on webpack only for some type of files

Tags: express, webpack, ejs, webpack-hmr, webpack-5

I have been struggling for over two days to come up with the perfect setup for `webpack` when using `express` and `EJS`.

This is where I am at at the moment:

https://github.com/ZeldOcarina/webpack-express-ejs-setup

Right now I have HMR enabled for SCSS and front-end JS changes.

The last thing I need to add is live reload on views/ejs changes. It works if I change `liveReload` to `true` on `webpack.dev.js` but then `HMR` breaks as everything reloads.

I can't find a way to reload only for `EJS` file changes.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made it guys!

The way is to use `chokidar` directly in the `before` `devServer` hook:

```
    devServer: {
        contentBase: "./src/",
        before(app, server) {
          chokidar.watch("./views").on(
            "all",
            debounce(function () {
              console.log("THIS IS HAPPENING!!!!!!");
              server.sockWrite(server.sockets, "content-changed");
            })
          );
        },
[...rest of devServer configuration]
```

`debounce` is a `lodash` function. To check the full configuration please refer to the `GitHub` repo in the question, I'll leave that open! :)